# Javascript: pass var to object literal

Tags: javascript, object-literal

I'm having a problem with this code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#city_input').autocomplete({
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {
            alert(suggestion.data);
            window.latlng = suggestion.data;
        }
    });

    $('#fs_input').autocomplete({
        params: { "latlng" : window.latlng, "latlng2" : '99.9999,-99.9999' },       
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {
            alert(window.latlng);
        }       
    });
});
```

This is an autocomplete script. First the user selects a suggestion on #city_input. Doing that, it sets the value for `window.latlng`.

Then next, the user needs to select a suggestion on #fs_input. The problem I'm having is that, in the "params" property, the `"latlng" : window.latlng` property is not being set. Just for tests, I also created another property, seen in the code, `latlng2` which is working fine. Also, a little below, I'm doing an `alert(window.latlng)` to check the value and it alerts the expected value.

So the question is, why `"latlng" : window.latlng` is not being set? Maybe I'm not supposed to pass a variable to an object liberal property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is being set. It's simply that it has no value at the point when you're setting it.

The value isn't computed dynamically after `#city_input`'s `onSelect` callback fires, it's being computed once when the script first loads, *long* before you ever assign to it.

```
$('#city_input').autocomplete({
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
        alert(suggestion.data);
        # you assign here, in a callback that executes some time after the page loads
        window.latlng = suggestion.data;
    }
});

$('#fs_input').autocomplete({
    # however, you *read* the value here, immediately on page load, long before `onSelect` ever runs
    # window.latlng is "undefined" at the point `params` is created.
    params: { "latlng" : window.latlng, "latlng2" : '99.9999,-99.9999' },       
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
        alert(window.latlng);
    }

});
```

If you want a value selected in the `onSelect` callback to be used in the `autocomplete` for a different element, you need to wait to initialize the autocomplete until after a value is selected and actually available:

```
$('#city_input').autocomplete({
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
        alert(suggestion.data);
        window.latlng = suggestion.data;

        $('#fs_input').autocomplete({
            params: { "latlng" : window.latlng, "latlng2" : '99.9999,-99.9999' },       
            onSelect: function (suggestion) {
                alert(window.latlng);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, I'm guessing that the `onSelect` function doesn't execute until a user has selected an item. However, the 'params' object is created when the `autocomplete` function is invoked, which is immediate (before a value has been assigned).

You need to initialise autocomplete on #fs_input only when you know the value of `window.latlng` (i.e. after the user has selected it):

```
$(function () {
    $('#city_input').autocomplete({
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {
            alert(suggestion.data);
            window.latlng = suggestion.data;

            $('#fs_input').autocomplete({
                params: { "latlng" : window.latlng, "latlng2" : '99.9999,-99.9999' },       
                onSelect: function (suggestion) {
                    alert(window.latlng);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: hey, thanks, makes total sense, I wish I could award you also, user 'meagar' posted the same answer just 1 min before.